# How to get evaluated data in Apache Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning

I implemented a simple naive bayesian method which is just exactly same with the given example in spark's tutorials. Here is how I implemented it:

```
public void applyNaiveBayes(String fileWithBinaryLabelsPath){
    Dataset<Row> dataFrame =
            sparkBase.getSpark().read().format("libsvm").load(fileWithBinaryLabelsPath);
    Dataset<Row>[] splits = dataFrame.randomSplit(new double[]{0.8, 0.2}, 1234L);
    Dataset<Row> train = splits[0];
    Dataset<Row> test = splits[1];

    NaiveBayes nb = new NaiveBayes();

    NaiveBayesModel model = nb.fit(train);

    Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(test);
    predictions.show();

    MulticlassClassificationEvaluator evaluator = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
            .setLabelCol("label")
            .setPredictionCol("prediction")
            .setMetricName("accuracy");

    double accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions);
    System.out.println("Test set accuracy = " + accuracy);
}
```

It works well. But I need one more thing. Here I use %20 of my data as test data. After the calculations I want to get the result data, I mean what naive bayes predicted for every row. How can I do that in java?

Comment: you want to extract predictions into the files?

Comment: @mangusta Yes I want that.

Comment: @mangusta Thank you, may I ask you one more question? How can I get precision and recall values in naive bayes, can you write or give a link of a resource about it? Thanks again.

Comment: @mangusta Thanks again, but what if it was a binary classification with naive bayes? Then I can not use weightedPrecision. And spark gives `parameter metricName given invalid value weightedPrecision.` error. What is the other metrics that we can use. Can you give a list or a link to reach out that? Thank you

Comment: @mangusta Thank you! Can you organize what you wrote and give an answer here, so that I can accept and others who are searching for these can see easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save predictions dataset into file, convert Dataset into JavaRDD and write JavaRDD into the file by issuing `predictions.javaRDD().saveAsTextFile(<file path>);`

Below is the metrics for Multiclass Classification evaluator:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/evaluation/MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.html#metricName--

Since you're using Naive Bayes model with binary classification, you need to use Binary Classification evaluator instead:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/evaluation/BinaryClassificationEvaluator.html